# How can I exclude specific text value in XPath?

Tags: html, css, ruby, xpath, nokogiri

I want to show DEF, not including ABC:

```
<ul class="view5">
    <li>
        <a href="/prd/detail_cate.jsp?item_cd=35386060" class="prdLink">
                <span class="prd_wrap">
                <img src="//itemimage.cjmall.com/goods_images/35/060/35386060J.jpg" alt="" onerror='this.src="http://itemimage.cjmall.com/goods_images/imageJ.jpg"'/>
                &nbsp;</span>
            <span class="prdTit">
                <B><FONT COLOR=#FF0000>ABC</FONT></B>DEF
            </span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

My code is:

```
@html.xpath('//ul[contains(@class,"view5")]//li//a[contains(@class,"prdLink")]//span[contains(@class,"prdTit")]').text
```

How can I modify my code to show just 'DEF', NOT including 'ABC'?

Comment: Can you give a more general description of what you want to extract vs. what you want to exclude? E.g. all text that is in the `<span class="prdTit">` element and is not in any child element of that `span`?

Answer (score 0):

You're making it a lot harder than it has to be. If you want to show "DEF", then remove "ABC". I'd go about it like:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(<<EOT)
<ul class="view5">
    <li>
        <a href="/prd/detail_cate.jsp?item_cd=35386060" class="prdLink">
            <span class="prdTit">
                <B><FONT COLOR=#FF0000>ABC</FONT></B>DEF
            </span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
EOT

doc.at('.prdTit b').remove
puts doc.to_html
# >> <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
# >> <html><body>
# >> <ul class="view5">
# >>     <li>
# >>         <a href="/prd/detail_cate.jsp?item_cd=35386060" class="prdLink">
# >>             <span class="prdTit">
# >>                 DEF
# >>             </span>
# >>         </a>
# >>     </li>
# >> </ul>
# >> </body></html>
```